# Swift Firebase Nested Queries and Concurrency in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, collectionview

Alright now I am getting really mad at this maybe because I don't have good conceptual understanding of this topic. I want to access post of friends of logged in user. I am already fetching friends of the logged in user.

I am then using the `fetchedFriend.uid` to search for post in another firebase collection named ("posts").

Manager is where I have the logic to fetch friends.

I am not able to get these posts from firebase. Here is the code:

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("Posts")

 Manager.fetchFriends(viewer: loggedInUser) { (fetchedFriends) in
//I am getting fetchedFriends and the uid

        for friend in fetchedFriends {

            guard let friendUID = friend.uid else { return }
            print(friendUID)

                let collectionref = ref.whereField("authorID", isEqualTo: friendUID)
                collectionref.getDocuments(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }

                    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
                    print(snapshot.count)
                })
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am then using the uid in the for loop, querying with "authorID" == "friendUID". Then I am grabbing documents but those documents count is coming as 0.

I have three posts in firebase so that shouldn't be a problem.

Any help here would be appreciated. I would love if somebody could explain the concurrency in this particular example and how to tackle through such a problem.

Comment: You may be in need to add rules for documents? is it showing any error have you seen ?

Comment: seen means have you debugged it or not ?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan no issue with rules since I am able to fetch friends.

Comment: friends are also in documents?

Comment: can you show hierarchy for your documents ?